# Removing a column permanently from a data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a given data frame `mydf`, I removed a column from the data frame through:

```
mydf.drop('Z', axis=1)
```

However, in the following parts, the removed column `Z` is still there, e.g., when I write `print(mydf.sum())` after the previous cell, it gives me the sum of column `Z` with the sum of other columns. How can I delete the column `Z` **permanently**?

Comment: `.drop` by default returns a new dataframe. specify `inplace=True` if you don't want to re-assign `mydf`

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *assign it back to `mydf`*, if you want to reach a permanent change, i.e. do

```
mydf = mydf.drop('Z', axis=1)
```

instead.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you so much.